# SQL exact matching for words in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, match, sql-like

I'm trying to find all records that have an exact match to part of the word that I'm searching for.

For example if I was looking for all the records with the word `spire` in it, I don't want to retrieve the rows with `aspire` or `inspire`.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table
WHERE   name LIKE '%SearchedWord%'
```

Comment: You might want to consider a full text search, depending on the database you are using.  Also, you should tag your question with the database.

Comment: for MySQL : Select * from Table where regexp '[[:<:]]SearchWord[[:>:]]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split words from the `name` column, then an exact matching is needed.

Following `SplitWords` function is needed to be created. It gets a sentence, and returns words in it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitWords(@text varchar(8000))
   RETURNS @words TABLE (
      pos smallint primary key,
      value varchar(8000)
   )
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE
      @pos smallint,
      @i smallint,
      @j smallint,
      @s varchar(8000)

   SET @pos = 1
   WHILE @pos <= LEN(@text) 
   BEGIN 
      SET @i = CHARINDEX(' ', @text, @pos)
      SET @j = CHARINDEX(',', @text, @pos)
      IF @i > 0 OR @j > 0
      BEGIN
         IF @i = 0 OR (@j > 0 AND @j < @i)
            SET @i = @j

         IF @i > @pos
         BEGIN
            -- @i now holds the earliest delimiter in the string
            SET @s = SUBSTRING(@text, @pos, @i - @pos)

            INSERT INTO @words
            VALUES (@pos, @s)
         END 
         SET @pos = @i + 1

         WHILE @pos < LEN(@text) 
            AND SUBSTRING(@text, @pos, 1) IN (' ', ',')
            SET @pos = @pos + 1 
      END 
      ELSE 
      BEGIN 
         INSERT INTO @words 
         VALUES (@pos, SUBSTRING(@text, @pos, LEN(@text) - @pos + 1))

         SET @pos = LEN(@text) + 1 
      END 
   END 
   RETURN 
END
```

Then do the following `SELECT` statement for exact matching of the words used in the `name` column:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [Table]
WHERE   'SearchedWord' IN (SELECT value FROM dbo.SplitWords(name))
```

Answer (score 1):

Add spaces before and after both name and like pattern:

```
select * from Table where ' ' || name || ' ' like '% SearchWord %'
```

`||` is ANSI SQL concatenation. Some products have `+` or `concat()` instead.

Comment: Adding spaces in the like means it only searches for the word where there are spaces in it, I don't know if the space is going to be before or after the word im trying to find. Also what should the contact on name do, that's the column in trying to search and just gives me no results if I try to replicate it for sql server?